# Showing webView in Cordova before API has loaded

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap / Cordova to build an application for iOS and Android. With the standard behaviour, the webView is not shown until the JavaScript has been initialised and the Cordova API is ready.  So until I call:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
```

... the screen is entirely blank.  Only once the call to deviceready is initialised and the Cordova API has loaded is the webView made visible.

I would like to show the webView as soon as possible, with no delay, so that the static HTML elements appear almost instantly, regardless of the Javascript state.  I've got a very basic knowledge of Objective C and have had a look through the code but the Cordova library is big and I haven't yet found out how and when the webView is displayed.

Does anyone know how I can show the webView as soon as the Objective C side has loaded, regardless of whether the Cordova API is ready yet or not?  (And what downsides there might be to that if any?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've noticed the same thing, at least on Android. Would love to know if there's a way to switch this behavior.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out?